# Drupal theme code to work out if you are editing a node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes

Does anyone know the php code to check if you are in edit mode? I want to edit how my theme looks when in edit mode so need to work out if I am or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also make a page template to handle this. Check this from http://drupal.org/node/190815:

> The list of suggested template files
>   in order of specificity based on
>   internal paths. One suggestion is made
>   for every element of the current path,
>   though numeric elements are not
>   carried to subsequent suggestions. For
>   example,
>   "http://www.example.com/node/1/edit"
>   would result in the following
>   suggestions:
>
> 1. page-node-edit.tpl.php
> 2. page-node-1.tpl.php
> 3. page-node.tpl.php
> 4. page.tpl.php

Answer (score 11):

You can check url arguments as shown [here](http://drupal.org/node/122578).

```
if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == 'edit'){ /*...*/}
```